# Get count for the last 90 days in 30 days groups Oracle BI

Tags: sql, oracle, date

How do I do I groupby and get the count per 30 days in a 90 days date range ?

```
SELECT 
x ,
y ,
count (y) 
FROM tbl
WHERE date BETWEEN 20220220 AND 20220520 
GROUP BY x , y
```

I want to breakdown the date into 30 days batches from 20220220 to 20220520 and get the count of for each 30 day interval as different columns

Comment: Use conditional aggregation with count: `count(case when your_date >= date '2022-05-20' - 30 then 1 end` etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT x,
       y,
       count(y),
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN date_column >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 89
         AND  date_column <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 59
         THEN Y
         END
       ) AS cnt_first_30,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN date_column >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 59
         AND  date_column <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 29
         THEN Y
         END
       ) AS cnt_second_30,
       COUNT(
         CASE
         WHEN date_column >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 29
         AND  date_column <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1
         THEN Y
         END
       ) AS cnt_third_30
FROM   tbl
WHERE  date_column >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 89
AND    date_column <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1
GROUP BY
       x,
       y
```